# Intuition for compact embedding of $H^1([0,1])$ in $L^2([0,1])$?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes

A compact operator is associated with 'smoothing', i.e. a function will have more regularity after a compact operator has acted upon it.

So if we take $\phi \in H^1([0,1])$ and let $I:H^1([0,1]) \to L^2([0,1])$ act on it, where $I$ is the compact embedding operator, in what way does $I\phi = \phi$ have more regularity? Because the function still 'looks' the same? All we seem to have done is change the norm from the $H^1$ norm to the $L^2$ norm..so in what way has the function been smoothed or regularized by this embedding operation?

Comment: Where did you hear this interpretation of compact? It's new to me

Comment: Well, for example, if an integral operator with a continuous (or weakly singular) kernel acts on a function then the resulting function will have more regularity. For instance the single layer potential in potential theory maps functions from $L^2(\partial\Omega) \to H^1(\partial \Omega)$ for some bounded domain $\Omega$. Here the regularity has clearly improved.

Comment: But for a compact embedding such as the operator $I$ in my original post it seems that regularity is lost! Can someone clarify notions of regularity with regards to compact embeddings and compact integral operators as it seems the effect of a compact operator is completely different in these two cases?

Comment: @eurocoder What's to be clarified? Yes, the effect is completely different in those two cases. It's simply not true that a compact operator necessarily has anything to do with smoothing. A compact operator is not the same thing as a compact integral operator. You've jumped to conclusions based on a few examples, and those conclusions are simply wrong.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Ok, so the set of compact integral operators is a subset of all compact operators, and while compact integral operators lead to a smoothing effect, compact operators in general don't, have I got that right? So what is the intuition for compact operators in general if we can't think of them as smoothing operators? Is it simply the axioms/definitions associated with them (such as being the limit of finite rank operators) or is there something more intuitive that can be said about them? Up to now I just thought 'smoothing effect' when I saw a compact operator!